SecureEditText in Android
Context: Fridum is a tool that can be used for penetration testing in Android. it can take a dump of an app's memory/heap and extract all strings.
Problem: I am using fridump to take a dump for my app after login. I can see user credentials(username and password) in the dump. these are the intermediate strings stored by EditText in the heap.
for example, if you type username "jondoe" in edit text. I can see the following strings
j, jo, jon, jond, jondo, jondoe
I want to clear the heap as soon I login so that the heap dump does not have the credentials.
What I have tried yet:

Clearing the edit text: et.text.clear()
Custome EditText :

class SecureEditText: AppCompatEditText {

    private var charArray: CharArray = CharArray(0)

        // Other constructers
        private fun init() {

        // TextWatcher to track input and accumulate characters into a CharArray
        addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence ? , start : Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence ? , start : Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                // Update the char array with the latest input
                charArray = CharArray(s?.length ?  : 0)
                    s?.forEachIndexed {
                    index,
                    c->
                    charArray[index] = c
                }
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable ? ) {}
        })
    }

    fun clearSecureText() {
        // Overwrite the CharArray to clear sensitive data from memory
        charArray.fill('\u0000')
        // Clear the EditText content
        text?.clear()
    }

}


However, the above approaches do not work at all. Even if we try to encrypt the text, the plain text will still be there in the heap stored by EditText itself.
I am out of ideas now. Please help me here.
Thanks in advance.

To be clear you are trying to prevent data access on a rooted device/emulator running a frida-server or a compromised APK with a frida payload? At a guess you would have to rewrite EditText class to be more 'secure' but I'm not sure what threat vector you are trying to prevent given that device or APK is no longer intact and has been compromised.

@MorrisonChang I am concerned about the security of my app and credentials on rooted devices. I know I can add a rooted device check but we also know that check can also be bypassed by Frida itself. So I wanted if I could stop EditText from storing strings in the heap.
Also curious about here whether it is possible with existing EditText or not and if not can we design a Custom EditText without involving storing strings in the heap?

If the app/device is compromised any attacker can trace your code to see the values or capture user input at the system level. The heap strings may be Java StringBuffer related but you are free to write your own EditText as it is all open source. Assuming you are doing server side monitoring, any client side hardening will be done with a trade-off in your development time / time the attacker will spend to either get credentials or data.
